# Ajuda com jest ERRO : 'Test suite failed to runReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined'

Tags: javascript, front-end, tdd, jest

Estou iniciando em TDD , estou usando `jest` para aprender. Porém estou com uma dúvida: 
Estou testando o seguinte código :

```
export const search = (query, type) => {
  return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=${query}&type=${type}`)
    .then(dataJson => dataJson.json())
    .then(res => res)
    .catch(err => err)
}
export const searchArtists = query => search(query, 'artist')
export const searchAlbums = query => search(query, 'albums')
export const searchTracks = query => search(query, 'tracks')
export const searchPlaylists = query => search(query, 'playlists')
```

**Teste** :

```
it('should searchArtist return data from promise', () => {
      const resposta = Promise.resolve({ name: 'drake' })
      const fakeJson = Promise.resolve({ json: () => resposta })
      mockFetch.mockImplementation(() => fakeJson)
      expect(searchTracks('drake')).resolves.toEqual({ name: 'drake' })
    })
```

O teste assim passa , porém se eu alterar o código testado e usar `async/await` :

```
export const search = (query, type) => {
  const dataJSON = await fetch(`https://api.spotify.co/v1/search?q=${query}type=${type}`)
const response = dataJSON.json()
return response
}
export const searchArtists = query => search(query, 'artist')
export const searchAlbums = query => search(query, 'albums')
export const searchTracks = query => search(query, 'tracks')
export const searchPlaylists = query => search(query, 'playlists')
```

Aparece este erro :

> 'Test suite failed to runReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not
>   defined'

Answer (score 0):

Pode postar o seu package.json e .babelrc?

Encontrei esta [resposta](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3126#issuecomment-465926747) em uma issue no GitHub que pode resolver o seu problema.

Pelo que vi o jest usava o @babel/polyfill para incluir a função regeneratorRuntime, entretanto, nas últimas versões foi removida esta lib e ficou a cargo do desenvolvedor adicioná-lo ao projeto.

Em meu projeto tenho no package.json o **jest:^23.5.0** e **@babel/polyfill:^7.2.5** funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: meu .babelrc esta assim : `{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current",
          "edge": "14",
          "firefox": "51",
          "chrome": "54",
          "safari": "10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
} `